# Share AWS KOPS user with another developer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kops

I have created a development deployment for an application using kops, kubectl, and EC2.

When I set up this deployment, I created a Kops IAM user as specified in [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/aws.md) guide. Everything has worked fine for me managing this deployment.

I am now leaving the project for another job and have to allow someone else 
to take over this deployment. I tried having them use `aws configure` and enter the appropriate kops IAM user creds, but the kops user still does not show up for this person when they run `aws iam list-users`.

*What is the best way to share this IAM user with this new developer?*

I have stumbled upon [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) which states I can Delegate Access Across AWS Accounts Using IAM Roles, but I am not sure if this is the correct solution? Shouldn't the new developer just be able to enter the Kops IAM user cred info to access its resources?

Forgive me, for I am not very experienced with aws-cli and this deployment process. I just took on this responsibility on our team because no one else was confident they could do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to enter the AWS Console as the Root.  Go to IAM and select the kops user.  In the Security credentials tab, create a new access key and share the credentials with the other developer by forwarding him/her the csv file.  Once he/she downloads the csv have them try the `aws configure` and enter the new access credentials.  Letme know if this works!

Comment: Thanks! Root user was able to do this for me and it seems to have worked.

Comment: Out of curiosity what's the best way to manage `kops` IAM if there are multiple developers? You can generate only 2 API keys per user on AWS, so I can't create more than 2 unique access keys for different devs, we need to share the key_id and secret, which is not ideal.